# SignalR - client connection management manually by server

Tags: c#, websocket, connection, signalr

I'm using signalR for having alive connection between clients and webapis in the server. we have a lot of groups in which there are 3 types of clients. android app, web app and raspberry device (IoT) and they have to keep a specific status updated all the time (immediately after status changed in the database) and check server for get and post commands and responses.

But i think having alive connection (websocket) all the time will drain battery of raspberry. so i think if there is a solution for handle clients connections manually in an arbitrary time schedule.

So can i open and close connection of clients from server (hub) in the arbitrary time schedule and repeat it every day?

For example , i want open the connection of a group of clients from 3 to 5 (pm) and after that i want just open connection every 5 minutes and keep it alive for 1 second. and repeat it.

Maybe it seems stupid but i want signalR in scheduling time span. is there a better way?

Comment: Best way is to save last connection time.  Then when a conneciton is made you only have to send data that changed since last connection.

Comment: This question isn't so clear. Is there a reason that you can't have this timing logic on the client to connect and report in at the desired intervals?

Comment: @jdweng do you mean it depends on the size of our data in transportation? for example if we don't send or receive any data , just having the open connection won't use battery?

Comment: @Jason i don't know a lot about signalR. it's my question. can i schedule or config times of connection or disconnection in clients and server in signalR? I want the connection to be opened or closed at specific times for each client (i want specify these times dynamically)

Comment: Part are CMOS logic which doesn't use much power unless the logic switches from 0 to 1, or 1 to 0.  It is more important to shut down the as many clocks as possible.   Usually if you put the deivce in a deep sleep mode you will save more power and it will automatically shutdown the UART clock.

Comment: It's not clear to me the reason why you have selected signalR. Servers cannot establish connections with clients, so if you want to close the connection, the client is going to need to reinitialize. From what I see in your question, it would appear to me that a timer that fires every x minutes on the client that calls a rest api accepting the parameters and returning the next timeout with the response would suffice. Another thing to consider, is to measure the impact of a signalR connection and see if this is even a problem.